# How can I lock a sqlite database?

Tags: sqlite

We've had issues in the past where a rogue process was keeping a sqlite db locked. I've written some code to notify us if this is happening, but need to test it.

How can I deliberately lock up a sqlite database, so that I can check if it's locked?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Execute these statements:

```
PRAGMA locking_mode = EXCLUSIVE;
BEGIN EXCLUSIVE;
```

This will lock whole database until you execute:

```
COMMIT;
// turn off exclusive locking mode
PRAGMA locking_mode = NORMAL; 
// for locking mode to actually take effect, perform any read or write operation on any table:
SELECT * FROM any_table LIMIT 1;
```

For simplicity, you can do this using `sqlite3` command line utility.

For more info, see [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_locking_mode).

Comment: Is python `conn.commit()` is the same with this `COMMIT`? Or should I do `conn.execute('COMMIT')?`

Comment: I believe answer to this is yes, it is equivalent

Comment: From the documentation *"When the locking-mode is set to EXCLUSIVE, the database connection never releases file-locks."* But you say something contradicting "*This will lock whole database until you execute: `COMMIT;`"*. Is the lock really released after `COMMIT;` or never released?

Comment: @phinz, thanks for digging into this. I have updated my answer - to release lock, you need to turn off exclusive locking mode and perform any read or write operation. I tested it locally, lock is indeed released after that.